# Disregard environment indent for equation

Tags: lists, indentation

I have a large equation in nested `itemize`-environments, which creates a lot of indention for the equation, such the equation is only placed on the right side of the page. It would look nicer if the equation was centered w.r.t. to the text area and disregard the base indention from the `itemize`-environments. 
Is it possible to somehow disable the indention for one equation?

MWE:

```
\documentclass{memoir}
\begin{document}
\begin{itemize}
  \item Item 1
    \begin{itemize}
      \item Item 1.1
        \begin{itemize}
          \item Item 1.1.1
            Text which should be indented
            % this equation should be positioned just as if it was not contained in any itemize-environment
            \[ 
              1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1
            \]
            Text which should be indented
        \end{itemize}
    \end{itemize}
\end{itemize}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
\documentclass{memoir}

\begin{document}
\begin{itemize}
  \item Item 1
    \begin{itemize}
      \item Item 1.1
        \begin{itemize}
          \item Item 1.1.1
            Text which should be indented
            % this equation should be positioned just as if it was not contained in any itemize-environment
            \[
\displayindent0pt
\displaywidth\textwidth
              1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1
            \]
            Text which should be indented
        \end{itemize}
    \end{itemize}
\end{itemize}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 3):

The cumulative list indentations are given by `\leftmargini+\leftmarginii+\leftmarginiii` - one for each of the lists:

[image]

```
\documentclass{memoir}
\usepackage{showframe}
\begin{document}
\begin{itemize}
  \item Item 1
    \begin{itemize}
      \item Item 1.1
        \begin{itemize}
          \item Item 1.1.1
            Text which should be indented
            % this equation should be positioned just as if it was not contained in any itemize-environment
            \[ 
              \hspace*{\dimexpr-\leftmargini-\leftmarginii-\leftmarginiii}
              1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1
            \]
            Text which should be indented
        \end{itemize}
    \end{itemize}
\end{itemize}
\end{document}
```

Comment: This technique seems to also work for `align*`, which I didn't ask for but also need.

Answer (score 1):

```
\documentclass{memoir}
\begin{document}
\begin{itemize}
  \item Item 1
    \begin{itemize}
      \item Item 1.1
        \begin{itemize}
          \item Item 1.1.1
            Text which should be indented\par
            % this equation should be positioned just as if it was not contained in any itemize-environment
            \hspace*{\dimexpr-\leftmargini-\leftmarginii-\leftmarginiii}\parbox{\linewidth}{%
            \[ 
              1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1
            \]}\par
            Text which should be indented
        \end{itemize}
    \end{itemize}
\end{itemize}

  \[ 
     1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1
  \]
\end{document}
```

[image]